# Google Maps Api v3 - Click marker, zoom then open window on 2nd click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map that displays store locations throughout the U.S. using custom markers. When someone clicks on a marker (1st click) I want to zoom to that area, which may contain multiple markers. Then when they click on a marker within that zoomed area (2nd click), it should display an info window with information about that store.

What I have is not working totally right. It works the way I want *IF* the 2nd click happens to be the same marker they clicked the first time. If it is a different marker within the zoomed area, it just pans and centers on that marker. Then I have to click a 3rd time to open the info window.

Here's my code:

```
          function(map, marker){      
          $(marker).click(function() {
             map.setZoom(8),
             map.panTo(marker.getPosition(),
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                   $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<p style=\"font-size:95%;\"><span class=\"red padR5\" style=\"font-weight: bold;\">$city</span><a href=\"#/locate-sola-salons/city/$url_title/C$city_id/\" id=\"$url_title\" title=\"$city\" style=\"border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;\">See Details</a></p><p>$address2</p><p>$phone</p>'}, this); 
                  })
             );
        });
```

Is there a way that I can accomplish what I want in only 2 clicks instead of 3?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to set a flag saying whether the map should pan/zoom on marker click or if it should open an info window. Or perhaps you could check the current zoom level and determine which action to take.

Comment: I ended up just setting a counter inside the click function. Once the counter is > 0 then show the info window instead of panTo().